# Trouble publishing .NET MAUI application to Microsoft App store

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

Help! Hello everybody, I am attempting to publish my .NET MAUI app to the Microsoft app store in preparation for an interview I have coming up in a few weeks.

I am having an issue where:

- the exe installed by the msix file fails to run unless stored in a directory containing all of its associated dll files and other dependencies such as images.
- I cannot pack this into an msix upload for the Microsoft store because the Microsoft store won't permit me to upload any msixupload file that contains more than 16 files. I'm quite sure there are several hundred files at the moment, but without all of them, my.exe program won't run.

**Any solutions for packaging the .dlls and exe into one file for publication to the Microsoft app store, or workarounds to produce a publishable .msix/msixupload file?**

---

**Sidenote,** when I try to **publish directly to the Microsoft store using Visual Studio,** I get the **error** shown at the bottom of this post.

- Alternatively I am currently publishing this using sideloading. The .exe DOES successfully run upon being installed by the msix, but again, only when all associated dependency files are present.

Tried many different things. Packaging applications, YouTube, publishing directly with Visual Studio. Cannot figure out a solution. Or how to use some of this packaging software.

View Publishing Details:
Package is being submitted to the Microsoft Store. Getting application information...

```
Error submitting to Microsoft Store. Please check your submission in Windows Dev Center.  

Microsoft.VisualStudio.ContinuousPublishing.HttpRequestFailedException:
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":**"A valid account could not be found with 
given authorization token.** Correlationid=da339ee3-b0da-42a8-9c92-5ca249c84c79"}  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ContinuousPublishing.IngestionClient.<InvokeAsync>d_14'1.MoveNext()....
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Thank you, I removed the photo.

Comment: Took me awhile to realize you have TWO different issues. StackOverflow works best with ONE issue per question. This avoids confusion when people are looking at title, question, answers. Will edit question slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you graciously @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: You can check this issue [which shows how to publish the the maui app in the microsoft store](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4329) sucessfully.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this! Unfortunately upon following the instructions in that post, I still cannot launch my program (crashes on launch) from the .msix file. The only way I have been able to get this to work is to create a self-contained executable which needs to be present among all its dependencies to launch.

Comment: May be you can try a new project, you can make sure the cause of crashes on launch is your project or the vs.